# Webrtc app not working on local host?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, screensharing

I am using a WebRTC demo application for screen sharing. The demo works perfectly fine but when I try to run the same code in localhost or my own remote server, the code doesn't run. 
Any ideas on how can I fix this issue?

Comment: ScreenSharing only works on an SSL connection. Is your local web server hosting it as such?

Comment: no I don't have an ssl connection on my web server. @BenjaminTrent

Comment: Try that. You can even use a self signed cert but it will not work unless SSL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Screensharing in Chrome only works over an SSL connection(). You can use a self-signed cert and simply accept it in your browser(this is for Chrome < M36).

Also, for Chrome >M36 you must now use the [Chrome.desktopcapture API](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/TPQVKZnsF5g) and the usual way of modifying media constraints and enabling screen-sharing in Chrome internals will not work in newer versions of chrome.

The API is farely simple and MUCH more robust than the previous given option in the media constraints.